# How to run spring scheduled jobs only in specific year?

Tags: java, spring, spring-scheduled

```
@Scheduled(cron = "0 0 0 * * *")
```

This runs a spring scheduled job at midnight. How could I add the year excplicit where this job should run? (I just want to disable a job in test environment for this year, so I want to set 2016).

Comment: 7th parameter in cron expression is year so you can set over there

Comment: spring only allows 6 chars unfortunately...

Comment: 7th parameter is not mandatory.

Comment: You can compare the year with `if(Year.now().getValue == 2016)` inside your scheduled task.

Answer (score 3):

Spring scheduling cron only admit six parameters: second, minute, hour, day, month, weekday. You can see documentation here: https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/support/CronSequenceGenerator.html

Answer (score 1):

you can mention it by this way

```
@Scheduled(cron = "0 15 10 * * ? 2016")
```

Fire at 10:15 AM every day during the year 2016

for complete reference [schedule reference](https://javahunter.wordpress.com/2011/05/05/cronscheduler-in-spring/)

Comment: "cron expression must consist of 6 fields (found 7)"

Comment: i think you are not using Quartz trigger