# Cron expression for particular date with year

Tags: java, spring-boot, cron, scheduler

*I want to schedule a cron job using @Scheduler annotation. My requirement is to generate a job on 30 March 2023 5:30PM.*

> I can able to add date time and day using the expression
> `@Scheduler(crons = "0 30 17 30 3 ?")` and this expression working fine

> But there I can't add year, if I add year like
> `@Scheduler(crons = "0 30 17 30 3 ? 2023")` getting exception like
> `Cron expression must contain of 6 fields(found 7 in "0 30 17 30 3 ? 2023")`

*So, How can I make Cron expression along with year ??, please help me here*

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28808588/how-to-run-spring-scheduled-jobs-only-in-specific-year)

Comment: Quartz supports years in its cron expressions: [CronExpression](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/api/2.3.0/org/quartz/CronExpression.html). See also [Scheduling in Spring with Quartz](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-quartz-schedule). Caveat: I have never tried scheduling a job using a year (never needed it).

Answer (score 0):

First of all cron jobs are those jobs which will be run repeatedly given the cron expression. So you can't express a job which will be run only once with it.

What you need is `ThreadPoolTaskScheduler` it supports execution of runnable once with a given instant as a parameter of its `schedule` method.

1. Create an `AppConfig.java` file and expose a bean of `ThreadPoolTaskScheduler`

```java
@Configuration
public class AppConfig {

    @Bean
    public ThreadPoolTaskScheduler threadPoolTaskScheduler() {
        return ThreadPoolTaskScheduler();
    }
    
}
```

2. Create a `TaskExecutorService.java` file and inject the created bean of `ThreadPoolTaskScheduler` and use that to schedule any runnable task like follow:

```java
@Service
public class TaskExecutorService {

    private final ThreadPoolTaskScheduler threadPoolTaskScheduler;

    @Autowired
    public TaskExecutorService(ThreadPoolTaskScheduler threadPoolTaskScheduler) {
        this.threadPoolTaskScheduler = threadPoolTaskScheduler;
    }

    public void scheduleOnce(Runnable runnable, Instant runAt) {
        threadPoolTaskScheduler.schedule(runnable, runAt);
    }
}
```

3. Now use the `scheduleOnce` method to schedule your task with any time and date you like.

Check out this blog post for reference. `https://www.baeldung.com/spring-task-scheduler#threadpooltaskscheduler`